# В чем преимущество использования JQuery перед использованием голого JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

В чем преимущество использования JQuery перед использованием голого JavaScript?

В каких случаях лучше использовать одно, а в каких другое?

Comment: В чём отличие PHP от WordPress?

Comment: Как у человека с таким рейтингом могут быть такие примитивные вопросы?

Comment: @Vadizar, ну я этот рейтинг на другой тематике набрал, далекой от веба.

Comment: В 2017 году — ни в чём, jQuery не нужен

Comment: @andreymal, т.е чистый JS юзают ? Я , просто, не в курсе всех трендов, так как только пытаюсь погрузиться в мир веба...

Comment: @iluxa1810 Тренды нынче — Angular 2, React, Babel :)

Comment: @andreymal, я правильно понимаю, что все эти фреймворки основаны на JS=> хорошо бы значить сам JS ?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Сам JS надо знать в любом случае, чтобы не получалось [вот так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif) ))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В рамках данного вопроса ограничусь следующими определениями:

Javascript - язык описания сценариев (или скриптовый язык), работающий на клиентской стороне (в браузере).

jQuery - это библиотека/фреймворк, построенный на Javascript. Огромная популярность jQuery объясняется в первую очередь тем, что эта библиотека решает основные проблемы кросс-браузерности и позволяет решить большинство стандартных задач быстрее и проще по сравнению с Javascript. Существуют и другие библиотеки, например Mootools.

Что лучше использовать - зависит от конкретной задачи. Есть приложения, для которых jQuery не подходит и скрипты пишутся непосредственно на Javascript либо разрабатывается свой фреймворк. Однако для большинства задач возможностей jQuery вполне достаточно.

Для тех, кто только начинает заниматься веб-разработкой, есть смысл ознакомиться с обеими технологиями - используя только jQuery, вы не изучите нюансов JavaScript, а использование только JavaScript может замедлить время разработки и привести к проблемам кросс-браузерной совместимости - которые как раз решены в jQuery.

*P.S. Немного статистики от W3techs: 
25,2% сайтов в мире вообще не использует Javascript.
jQuery используется более чем на 72% сайтов в мире, или на 96,5% сайтов, использующих Javascript.
Подробнее (там указаны и другие фреймворки, некоторые уже почти забытые): https://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/javascript_library/all*